# MVC 4 Application Using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently did a portion of the MVCMusicStore tutorial using MVC3 as directed. However, being that I have Visual Studio 2012, I'm attempting to use EF in an MVC4 application. I was attempting to add the using System.Data.Entity; directive and it was not found.

I know that I can probably just add the reference to it. But I'd like to know why it's not already available for my MVC4 project. Is there a new method of creating an Entity Framework supported application using MVC4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework is now being distributed separately from Visual Studio through the NuGet package management system as of Visual Studio 2012.  The reason for this is to decouple EF from the release of VS, so it can be released on a different time schedule.  They have also recently released EF as an open source framework, so it's being removed as a project from the .net framework release.

You have to use NuGet to install Entity Framework in your project.  Right click on the project and choose Manage Nuget Packages.  Make sure you select the Online tab in the dialog that opens, then in the search type Entity Framework and click Install.  You will then be able to add the using statement.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mystery Man (or is it really Mystere Man?). You saved me a big burden! I added the reference and still couldn't (obviously) use DbContext. Was lost. :) I appreciate it very much!